# Cross Browser Fix , OnScroll Function

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

```
window.onscroll = function()
{
if( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
var bodyId=document.getElementById('bodymain');
    if (bodyId.scrollTop > 187) {
    //make some div's position fixed
    } else {
           //make some div's position absolute

    }
}
}
```

This Code Works Fine For Chrome, But Doesn't Work For IE9. Can You Suggest A Cross-Browser Version Of This Code

Comment: Why are you checking for XHR capabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (scrollTop > 187) {
        //make some div's position fixed
    } else {
        //make some div's position absolute
    }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kxwUp/1/)

This should work fine in all browsers since IE7. It just won't run in IE6 as it doesn't support `position:fixed`.